# Is there a US banking product with free or very cheap ATM access in Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, international, atm

My family member plans to live in Canada but his income still comes from his investment in the U.S. Is there a bank product that let him withdraw money with cheap or free ATM fee in Canada, or/and let him transfer from his US account to Canada account online in a cheap rate?

Answer (score 2):

The [Charles Schwab High Yield Investor Checking Account](https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/banking_lending/checking_account) bank account has no foreign transaction fees and refunds all ATM fees worldwide. The one limitation would be that you have to open it as a linked account to a Schwab Brokerage account, but since both accounts are free and have no minimum balances, this shouldn't be a big issue.

> The Schwab Bank High Yield Investor Checking® account is available only as a linked account with a Schwab One® brokerage account. The Schwab One brokerage account has no minimum balance requirements, and there is no requirement to fund this account, when opened with a linked High Yield Investor Checking account
>
> 1: Unlimited ATM fee rebates apply to cash withdrawals using your Visa debit card wherever it is accepted ...
>
> 3: Schwab Bank does not assess foreign transaction fees (i.e., a fee to convert US Dollars to local currency) to debit cardholders
>
> [Schwab Bank High Yield Investor Checking® Account](https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/banking_lending/checking_account)